# How do I get my terminal to show the entire output of my command?

Tags: terminal, netstat

terminal command: `watch netstat -nalp`

I get an output, but I am not able to scroll down to see the majority of the output. I can only see as far down as I extend the bottom of the terminal (box). I have tried the up and down arrows, enter, tab, page up, page down; nothing works. Basically, I can only see what the extended terminal shows.

Also, when I "select all", I am able to, but within a second, it disappears before I can 'copy' it. The highlighted screen becomes 'un-highlighted'. I tried 'edit, select all' from the top of the terminal, and also, just highlighting it with the mouse. Same results.

I do not have any of these issues with "any" other commands, like typing `ip addr`, `ifconfig -a`, etc. I am able to scroll up and down, select all and it doesn't disappear, etc.

Does anyone have any idea why it is doing this, and how to fix it, if possible?

Comment: "Any other commands" do not start with `watch`. Are you aware what `watch` does?

Comment: Try to increate the interval between executions of the command: `watch -n 30 netstat -nalp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'watch' is re-executing the 'netstat -nalp' command, and re-drawing your screen to reflect any changes from the previous run.
Since 'watch' is using the 'curses' library, it is likely that it is able to minimise it's output to only that which is required to display the characters that change between runs. However, if you are trying to select text that is being 'redrawn', then you will find that some terminal emulators (e.g. 'putty') will re-set (unselect) your selected text.

(I note that OSX 'Terminal' does not suffer from this problem - there may be others).

What you might be able to do (depending on your 'stty' settings) is send the keystroke `'<CTRL>S'` (known as XOFF) to temporarily stop the screen from being updated.
Once you have selected and copied your selection, you can resume your terminal output by sending the keystroke `'<CTRL>Q'` (known as XON).

Comment: Thank you all. Getting rid of the "watch" fixed both issues. No, I did not know what 'watch' did; previously told to run 'watch netstat -nalp'. Thanks!

Comment: @sgu55 Good! If this solves your issue, please consider ["accepting" the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is the best way to show gratitude on this site.  Accepting an answer not only marks the question as resolved, but also signals to _future readers_ that the accepted answer actually solved the issue.  More information about this is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers